# Study the convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { \sin ^ { 6 } ( 1 + 2 n ^ { 2 } ) } { \sqrt { n ^ { 3 } + n + 1 } }$$
I try to use the following,
Since, $|\sin^6(1+2n^2)|<1$
Then the above series $$\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { \sin ^ { 6 } ( 1 + 2 n ^ { 2 } ) } { \sqrt { n ^ { 3 } + n + 1 } }=\sum \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$$
By $p$-series and comparison test
Thus, the above series converges absolutely.
Right or wrong ? Please help to tell me about other methods.

Comment: That's how I would have done it.

Comment: The equal sign isn't right. That should be "$<$". And you need not to put $| . |$ when there is $6$th power and real inputs.